# How to get only availability variation count in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

Hi I want to get only value availability from variation but data.variation.availability_html returns count and text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] Example and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following hooked functions to get availability count **for product variations**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'display_variation_availability_count', 10, 2 );
function display_variation_availability_count( $args, $product ) {
    // Targeting product variations with stock management enabled
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_type('variation') ) {
        $args['availability'] = __("Stock: ") . $product->get_stock_quantity();
        $args['class'] = 'stock-count';
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Or:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'display_variation_availability_count', 10, 2 );
function display_variation_availability_count( $availability, $product ) {
    // Targeting product variations with stock management enabled
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_type('variation') ) {
        $availability = __("Stock: ") . $product->get_stock_quantity();

    return $availability;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in your active theme like below structure woocommerce/templates/single-product/stock.php

Add below code to the file

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

?>
<?php echo wp_kses_post( $availability ); ?>
```

Get availability using product object can be done like below

```
$availability = $product->get_availability();
```